# Can I put custom objects on Google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I know that I can put markers on map and give them graphical background. But can I put custom objects on the map and attach them to position (yes, like a marker) AND add some kind of animations and transformations ? I want to add a lot of different objects on the map and animate them. For example I want to animate two guys shooting to themselves and put all of that on the google maps

Comment: Please add simply code showing you can add custom marker to Google Maps.

Comment: @BlackFrog I am sorry but could you extend your answer ? I'm not sure that I understand what you have in mind :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can make custom markers if you want and place them

Comment: by `custom marker` you understand object of `Marker` class with background ? But what if I want to put animated object using OpenGL and/or animated GIF ? I won't handle it by `Marker` class. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: You just need to use icon:icon-url when creating the marker.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at that